# Can you redirect to a web page based on whether a field exists in a microsoft sql database on wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have created a REST API that searches a microsoft sql db using a db lookup  mediator, I wish to redirect to a web page based on whether or not a UserCode field exists in my database. I do not receive an error when attempting to test my API but it does not redirect either. Please see my API code below that I have created on EI.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DBLookupAPI" context="/dblookup">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{UserCode}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Value" expression="get-property('uri.var.UserCode')"/>
         </log>
         <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.111\test;databaseName=UserDB</url>
                  <user>admin</user>
                  <password>admin</password>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>select UserCode from UserDB.dbo.Users where UserCode =?;</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('uri.var.UserCode ')" type="CHAR"/>
               <result name="foundnr" column="UserCode "/>
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Value" expression="get-property('foundnr')"/>
         </log>
         <filter source="boolean(get-property('foundnr'))" regex="true">
            <then>
               <log>
                  <property name="Message" value="Name Exists Lets redirect"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
               <property name="Location" value="https://wso2.com/"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <log>
                  <property name="Message" value="Name Does Not Exist Lets redirect"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
               <property name="Location" value="https://www.youtube.com/"/>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

My wso2-ei-api log says

```
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-10 15:57:12,665]  INFO {API_LOGGER.DBLookupAPI} - Value = Sash18
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-10 15:57:12,727]  INFO {API_LOGGER.DBLookupAPI} - Value = Sash18
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-10 15:57:12,728]  INFO {API_LOGGER.DBLookupAPI} - To: /dblookup/Sash18, MessageID: urn:uuid:e37541a7-eabd-4d70-8bde-6f9dfc2ebfee, Direction: request, Message = Name Exists Lets redirect
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-10 15:57:19,067]  INFO {API_LOGGER.DBLookupAPI} - Value = No
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-10 15:57:19,120]  INFO {API_LOGGER.DBLookupAPI} - Value = null
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-10 15:57:19,121]  INFO {API_LOGGER.DBLookupAPI} - To: /dblookup/No, MessageID: urn:uuid:6fd1a264-5f1b-45d8-bcc4-b52a079abbd3, Direction: request, HTTP_SC = 302, Location = https://www.youtube.com/
```

First I enter Sash18, which is a UserCode in my db and then I enter no which is not a UserCode in my db.

I have even attempted to create an API calling a data service instead of using a db lookup mediator and this approach did not redirect either. (I have this posted as another question)

Answer (score 1):

The results of the `DBLookupMediator` will be set to a property called `foundnr`. So in your `FileterMediator` you need to check the availability of this property.

```xml
<filter source="boolean(get-property('foundnr'))" regex="true">
    <then>
         <log>
            <property name="Message" value="Name Exists Lets redirect"/>
         </log>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Location" value="https://wso2.com/" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    </then>
    <else>
         <log>
            <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
            <property name="Location" value="https://www.youtube.com/"/>
          </log>
    </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: Hi, please note that when I implement your solution I get a TypeError: Failed to fetch response, whereas with the code in my post it just has a status cod of 200 but does not redirect.

Comment: @KelishaGovender is that coming from the Client? Probably it's getting redirected. Also, It's very important that you enable Wire logs in your server, then it's very easy to Debug the issue.

Comment: @KelishaGovender Also, with the new API, once you invoke the API, can you copy the full WSO2 log and add it to your question too?

Comment: Hi @ycr, I have updated my API in my post as well as added my wso2-ei-api logs. Please advise on whether or not this is how the logs are supposed to look.

Comment: Also, when I add the type as "string" in the then, it fives me a failed to fetch response.

Comment: @KelishaGovender from the logs it seems that the code works perfectly.  Please try to invoke the API with `curl` Something like this. `curl -vk https://YOUR_API_URL`. Then you should see how the response is sent and how the redirection happens.

Comment: When invoking the API with curl I get the following response, please advise.    C:\Windows\System32>curl -vk http://192.168.0.197:8280/dblookup
*   Trying 192.168.0.197:8280...
* Connected to 192.168.0.197 (192.168.0.197) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /dblookup HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.0.197:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2022 14:15:57 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.197 left intact

Comment: @KelishaGovender You are getting a 404. Your URL has to be `curl -vk http://192.168.0.197:8280/dblookup/Sash18`

Comment: Hi thank you for your assistance, it works. It's just when I add something that it not in my db, for example if I use the command curl -vk http://192.168.0.197:8280/dblookup/no it does not give back the redirect location

Comment: It says: C:\Windows\System32>curl -vk http://192.168.0.197:8280/dblookup/no
*   Trying 192.168.0.197:8280...
* Connected to 192.168.0.197 (192.168.0.197) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /dblookup/no HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.0.197:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept: */*
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Host: 192.168.0.197:8280
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
< Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2022 14:30:44 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.197 left intact

Comment: @KelishaGovender in your API, you just have logs in the else block. So refer the then block and do the same in else block.

Comment: I have updated my post with my updated else block and the outcome is still the same, even though it is now identical to my then block.

Comment: @KelishaGovender that's not possible. If you see the log `Name Exists Lets redirect` that means the properties will be set and the redirection should happen. May be add the `curl`  output to the question.

Comment: Hi, it now works. I just needed to add a scope:"transport". Thank you so much for all your assistance.

Comment: Is it possible to make the redirect link dynamic instead of hardcoding it? So that every time the url changes it does not have to be redeployed

Comment: @KelishaGovender Yes, you can set the `Location` Property from an Environment variable or from other properties.

Comment: How would you set it and call it in your API as an Environment Variable?